# What could cause a Visual Studio additional include path to fail?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, clearcase, freeglut

I'm relatively new to VS2010 in a new project, and am having an issue with the Configuration Manager. The group uses Clear Case for version control, and I am trying to include the freeglut library which is located in a VOB the project.sln I'm working on isn't in. The config spec is correctly built and it's pulling in the correct VOB. My issue is that when I have the relative path in the "Additional Include Paths" portion of C++->General in the Configuration manager e.g.:

../../../TopLevelVOB/GLUT/Release

Visual Studio tells me that it doesn't know that "freeglut.h" exists. However, when I put in the absolute path e.g.:

C:ClearCaseFolder/SNAPVIEW/TopLevelVOB/GLUT/Release

Visual Studio tells me that "freeglut.h" exists, and will attempt to compile. Then it tells me that it can't load "freeglut.lib" which also has the correct relative path in the Configuration Manager as part of the additional include paths. However, when I do the absolute path for the freeglut.lib the compiler does not work.

Have you encountered this before? Do you have an answer or some direction you could point me in? Many thanks!

Comment: "additional include paths" - include paths don't affect the link step. It needs to be in the additional *library* paths under Linker settings. Also, make sure your relative paths are relative to the *project* file (vcprojx), not the solution file (sln). The former is often in a subdirectory of the latter's folder. if they're the same folder, it obviously won't matter.

Comment: Try opening a shell window to the folder containing the project file, then testing the relative paths to the .h and .lib files. If that works, you might have a Clear Case setup problem.

Comment: WhozCraig, you were correct. I didn't have the path in the Library paths under the linker settings. That fixed my issue. Thanks a bunch!